# In-App Purchase from Amazon Apps & Games Developer for Android: An error occurred while processing your purchase

Tags: android, amazon-in-app-purchase

My App is working fine with APP tester. But when I release the app in [Amazon Apps & Games Developer][1]

I have imported sample app(1.0 version) from Apps-SDK.

I just changed code at one place in MySku.java

```
/*MY_MAGAZINE_MONTHLY(
        "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine.month",
        "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine");*/
```

with below lines

```
MY_MAGAZINE_MONTHLY(
        "com.mycompany.appname.iap.subscription.yearly",
        "com.mycompany.appname.iap.subscription");

//Up on click subscribe button, I am calling below method from SubScriptionFragment.java
public void subscribeNow(){
    String requestId = PurchasingManager
            .initiatePurchaseRequest(MySKU.MY_MAGAZINE_MONTHLY.getSku());
    PurchaseData purchaseData = purchaseDataStorage.newPurchaseData(requestId);
    Log.i(TAG, "onBuyMagazineMonthlyClick: requestId (" + requestId 
            + ") requestState (" + purchaseData.getRequestState() + ")");
}
```

Even after migrating to version 2.0 IAP

I am getting **"An error occurred while processing your purchase"**. See below image

![enter image description here][2]

Here is the Logcat

```
09-10 15:10:13.570: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onProductDataResponse: RequestStatus (SUCCESSFUL)
09-10 15:10:13.570: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onProductDataResponse: successful.  The item data map in this response includes the valid SKUs
09-10 15:10:13.570: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onProductDataResponse: 0 unavailable skus
09-10 15:10:13.867: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onProductDataResponse: RequestStatus (SUCCESSFUL)
09-10 15:10:13.867: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onProductDataResponse: successful.  The item data map in this response includes the valid SKUs
09-10 15:10:13.867: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onProductDataResponse: 0 unavailable skus
09-10 15:10:14.164: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onGetUserDataResponse: requestId (e74baa85-8fde-4c0b-a29d-48a96d895feb) userIdRequestStatus: SUCCESSFUL)
09-10 15:10:14.164: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onUserDataResponse: get user id (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=, marketplace (US) 
09-10 15:10:14.468: I/HomeActivity(2783):  onTabChanged 
09-10 15:10:15.023: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onGetUserDataResponse: requestId (a4778610-929a-479b-a460-ace04ae76c3a) userIdRequestStatus: SUCCESSFUL)
09-10 15:10:15.023: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onUserDataResponse: get user id (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=, marketplace (US) 
09-10 15:10:17.242: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onPurchaseUpdatesResponse: requestId (14786842-405d-4a5e-bf4f-e218e982a2e2) purchaseUpdatesResponseStatus (SUCCESSFUL) userId (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=)
09-10 15:10:17.242: D/SampleIAPManager(2783): getSubscriptionRecord: userId (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=)
09-10 15:10:17.242: D/SampleIAPManager(2783): getSubscriptionRecord: found 0 records
09-10 15:10:17.570: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onPurchaseUpdatesResponse: requestId (41f80cbe-1f76-435d-859f-0a1fcdebf684) purchaseUpdatesResponseStatus (SUCCESSFUL) userId (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=)
09-10 15:10:17.570: D/SampleIAPManager(2783): getSubscriptionRecord: userId (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=)
09-10 15:10:17.570: D/SampleIAPManager(2783): getSubscriptionRecord: found 0 records
09-10 15:10:25.148: D/HomeActivity(2783): onBuyMagazineClick: requestId (8de3c616-b5f6-41b9-98fa-ebb5d6dec9ce)
09-10 15:10:25.234: I/HomeActivity(2783): onPause
09-10 15:10:26.031: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2783): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-10 15:11:36.226: D/HomeActivity(2783): onResume: call getUserData
09-10 15:11:36.226: D/HomeActivity(2783): onResume: getPurchaseUpdates
09-10 15:11:36.242: D/HomeActivity(2783): onResume: call getUserData
09-10 15:11:36.242: D/HomeActivity(2783): onResume: getPurchaseUpdates
09-10 15:11:36.250: D/WebCore(2783): *-* Start browser instrument
09-10 15:11:36.258: D/WebCore(2783): *-* Start browser instrument
09-10 15:11:36.258: D/WebCore(2783): *-* Start browser instrument
09-10 15:11:36.383: I/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onPurchaseResponse: 
09-10 15:11:36.383: I/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onPurchaseResponse: requestId (8de3c616-b5f6-41b9-98fa-ebb5d6dec9ce) userId (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=) purchaseRequestStatus (FAILED)
09-10 15:11:36.383: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onPurchaseResponse: failed so remove purchase request from local storage
09-10 15:11:36.718: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onGetUserDataResponse: requestId (9b08e236-5783-49c3-94e6-554034d375df) userIdRequestStatus: SUCCESSFUL)
09-10 15:11:36.718: D/SampleIAPSubscriptionApp(2783): onUserDataResponse: get user id (OTsvlUq0dyCGLYHVJ0BnYW5ctox_mlRblmj2RURYn3E=, marketplace (US)
```

Comment: I migrated to version 2.0 . it is throwing purchaseRequestStatus (FAILED)

Answer (score 2):

Other people with what seems to be the same issue just cleared the cache & data from the markets. You can give it a try:

**On Amazon:**

1. Tap the "Quick Settings" (gear) icon in the upper right hand corner.
2. From the Quick Settings drop down menu, tap the "More..." icon.
3. From the "Settings" menu, tap "Applications."
4. In the Applications menu, tap to select "Amazon App Store." Tap on Clear data and Clear cache.

**Here are the sources:**

https://help.disney.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Where-s-My-Perry-Error-An-error-occured-while-processing-your-purchase-on-Kindle-Fire-Android-1390184965462?section=Games

http://androidforums.com/android-applications/460266-help-error-occurred-while-processing-your-purchase-please-try-again-later.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already did this, but no use for me

Comment: atleast give him an upvote :D..he did a google  search for you.. Respect his time  :D :P !

Comment: Haha thanks Noone, but that is sadly not the right answer! Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Sorry, it is not useful to me

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was worth putting here for all to see,but the exact same error message will appear if trying to buy you own app as a developer through Google Play.Thought some people would want to know ,this is detailed in the Google Wallet Terms and Conditions.